# Is there a way to check if random Generated Number existed in database? C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2013

I have this automatic LRN generate Numbers consist of 12 numbers only first i set "number" = 100000000000 + random numbers so example of output 100569815234 then that number will check if it is already existing in my database if not that number will use to register a student. but if it already existing in database I have this another generating random number same as the first random numbers but how can I check again if it already exist in database?

this is my code

inside form2_load*

```
        Random rnd = new Random(); //
        long firstLRN = rnd.Next(1000000000);
        long addLRN = 100000000000 + firstLRN;
        string FinalLRN = Convert.ToString(addLRN);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select LRN FROM Student_LRN where LRN = '" + FinalLRN + "'";

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            int countLRN = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                countLRN++;

            }
            if (countLRN == 0)
            {
                label_LRN.Text = FinalLRN;
            }
            else if (countLRN == 1)
            {
                long randomNewLRN = rnd.Next(1000000000);
                long newLRN = 100000000000 + randomNewLRN;
                string newFinalLRN = Convert.ToString(newLRN);
                label_LRN.Text = newFinalLRN;
                /*
                 * what if this another random generated number already existing again? what can i do with this?
                 */
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Please always use parameters instead of concatenating your sql queries. Look up "sql injection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do more than 1 query if the number exists, anyway with such a high values, it would resolve it in a little steps (1 or 2) with something like this code

```
Random rnd = new Random();
long firstLRN;
long addLRN;
string FinalLRN;

try
{
    // Set connection
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;

    // Generate the first random number
    firstLRN = rnd.Next(1000000000);
    addLRN = 100000000000 + firstLRN;
    FinalLRN = Convert.ToString(addLRN);

    // Query and if exists query with number++
    do {
        command.CommandText = "select LRN FROM Student_LRN where LRN = '" + FinalLRN + "'";

        // Execute the query and check if the number exists
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // If number exists add 1 to the number
        if (reader.Read()){
            addLRN++;
            FinalLRN = Convert.ToString(addLRN);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you used parameters (a much better habit), you could have updated the just value of the parameter.

Comment: Is a `while`  really optional ? I would end the loop with `while(true)`

Comment: Personally, I would always generate a new number if you expect the number to be random. Else, if you know your random number, there's an increased chance the number plus or minus one is also taken, which can be problematic

Comment: I have this problem where i need to close the connection to run the do while again over and over while there is a duplicate value... where can i put the connection.Close();?

Comment: lol while is not optional sorry, I wrote over the web, not over the code editor, I hope you understand the idea xD

Answer (score 0):

Extract your "check if it is already existing" logic into a method that you can call whenever needed. It can take the ID as a parameter and return a bool, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that unique number for registring a user, I wouldn't use a numeric value, but rather a [NewGuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8) :

```
// using System;

Guid LRN = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(LRN);
```

This outputs something like :

> df7df6cf-59b5-4bfb-87de-0d1e00c003a8